# Check splitBarWhenNarrow is true or not - programmatically - ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I need to check whether the `Activity` has a Bottom `ActionBar` (Split ActionBar) or not. How it could be checked programmatically ?

I have `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` for an `Activity` and the `Menu` options will at the Top `ActionBar` if the `Device Screen` is larger or in `Landscape mode`. I have to perform some color change on `Menu` Icons depending upon their position on `ActionBar`s (Top/Bottom).

Answer (score 1):

Simple. You use the ActionBarSherlocks `abs_split_action_bar_is_narrow` boolean value.

Now you can do something like this:

```
boolean isActionBarSplitted = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.split_action_bar);
if(isActionBarSplitted){
      // it's a phone -> split ActionBar
}
else{
     // it's a tablet -> no split ActionBar
}
```

Comment: This detects whether the split action bar is available, not whether it's in use. I suppose if you know that when you call this method that the split flag was specified in the manifest then this would be adequate.

Comment: Yes. For small screen devices, in the `Landscape Mode` this will not work as it return always `true` for `isActionBarSplitted`. Is there any way to check whether the `splitActionBar` is used or not dynamically ?

Comment: I have tried another fix, check the `Screen Orientation` if the `isActionBarSplitted` returns true and if its `Landscape`, then there is less chance for `splitActionBar`. This ugly trick works very well for almost all cases except very small screen devices (240x320/2.7"). Is there any valid solutions ?